# Using R to parse out Surveymonkey csv files

Tags: r, parsing, csv, surveymonkey

I'm trying to analyse a large survey created with surveymonkey which has hundreds of columns in the CSV file and the output format is difficult to use as the headers run over two lines.

- Has anybody found a simple way of managing the headers in the CSV file so that the analysis is manageable ?
- How do other people analyse results from Surveymonkey?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a *small* example of Surveymonkey output that demonstrates the problem? I can imagine a solution that uses `readLines` with `n=2` to read (and massage) the headers, and uses `read.csv` with `skip=2, header=FALSE` to get just the data ...

Comment: Next time when you run a survey, use LimeSurvey (http://www.limesurvey.org/) - it's open source and it has an Export to R facility that works reasonably well (disclosure: I wrote the export module)

Comment: @Ben, the headers in the file are two lines question name / number and then subquestions written out on the line beneath. In general, a total pain in the ass to deal with.

Comment: @Sean, within my organization I usually pull the *.sav (you need a paid account for that) as the csv is terribad to work with. The SPSS files can have some wonkiness, but it's not too bad to clean up (@Andrie, is also working on something for that too :)).

Comment: @Ben, in trying to create a small example I've discovered that the second line of the Surveymonkey CSV file appears to start with Null characters and R ignores this line when I use read.csv() or readLines().  Libreoffice can read this line though! was driving me nuts for a while!  Suggestions?

Comment: @Andrie thanks for that it certainly looks interesting and I'll keep it in mind for the future!  In this case the survey was done a year ago by somebody in another department and they needed help at the last minute...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What I did in the end was print out the headers using libreoffice labeled as V1,V2, etc. then I just read in the file as

```
 m1 <- read.csv('Sheet1.csv', header=FALSE, skip=1)
```

and then just did the analysis against m1$V10, m1$V23 etc...

To get around the mess of multiple columns I used the following little function

```
# function to merge columns into one with a space separator and then
# remove multiple spaces
mcols <- function(df, cols) {
    # e.g. mcols(df, c(14:18))
        exp <- paste('df[,', cols, ']', sep='', collapse=',' )
        # this creates something like...
        # "df[,14],df[,15],df[,16],df[,17],df[,18]"
        # now we just want to do a paste of this expression...
        nexp <- paste(" paste(", exp, ", sep=' ')")
        # so now nexp looks something like...
        # " paste( df[,14],df[,15],df[,16],df[,17],df[,18] , sep='')"
        # now we just need to parse this text... and eval() it...
        newcol <- eval(parse(text=nexp))
        newcol <- gsub('  *', ' ', newcol) # replace duplicate spaces by a single one
        newcol <- gsub('^ *', '', newcol) # remove leading spaces
        gsub(' *$', '', newcol) # remove trailing spaces
}
# mcols(df, c(14:18))
```

No doubt somebody will be able to clean this up!

To tidy up Likert-like scales I used:

```
# function to tidy c('Strongly Agree', 'Agree', 'Disagree', 'Strongly Disagree')
tidylik4 <- function(x) {
  xlevels <- c('Strongly Disagree', 'Disagree', 'Agree', 'Strongly Agree')
  y <- ifelse(x == '', NA, x)
  ordered(y, levels=xlevels)
}

for (i in 44:52) {
  m2[,i] <- tidylik4(m2[,i])
}
```

Feel free to comment as no doubt this will come up again!

Answer (score 10):

You can export it in a convenient form that fits R from Surveymonkey, see download responses in 'Advanced Spreadsheet Format'

[image: surveymonkey export]

Answer (score 4):

I have to deal with this pretty frequently, and having the headers on two columns is a bit painful. This function fixes that issue so that you only have a 1 row header to deal with. It also joins the multipunch questions so you have top: bottom style naming.

```
#' @param x The path to a surveymonkey csv file
fix_names <- function(x) {
  rs <- read.csv(
    x,
    nrows = 2,
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
    header = FALSE,
    check.names = FALSE, 
    na.strings = "",
    encoding = "UTF-8"
  )

  rs[rs == ""] <- NA
  rs[rs == "NA"] <- "Not applicable"
  rs[rs == "Response"] <- NA
  rs[rs == "Open-Ended Response"] <- NA

  nms <- c()

  for(i in 1:ncol(rs)) {

    current_top <- rs[1,i]
    current_bottom <- rs[2,i]

    if(i + 1 < ncol(rs)) {
      coming_top <- rs[1, i+1]
      coming_bottom <- rs[2, i+1]
    }

    if(is.na(coming_top) & !is.na(current_top) & (!is.na(current_bottom) | grepl("^Other", coming_bottom)))
      pre <- current_top

    if((is.na(current_top) & !is.na(current_bottom)) | (!is.na(current_top) & !is.na(current_bottom)))
      nms[i] <- paste0(c(pre, current_bottom), collapse = " - ")

    if(!is.na(current_top) & is.na(current_bottom))
      nms[i] <- current_top

  }


  nms
}
```

If you note, it returns the names only. I typically just read.csv with `...,skip=2, header = FALSE`, save to a variable and overwrite the names of the variable. It also helps ALOT to set your `na.strings` and `stringsAsFactor = FALSE`.

```
nms = fix_names("path/to/csv")
d = read.csv("path/to/csv", skip = 2, header = FALSE)
names(d) = nms
```

Answer (score 3):

As of November 2013, the webpage layout seems to have changed. Choose `Analyze results > Export All > All Responses Data > Original View > XLS+ (Open in advanced statistical and analytical software)`. Then go to Exports and download the file. You'll get raw data as first row = question headers / each following row = 1 response, possibly split between multiple files if you have many responses / questions.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The issue with the headers is that columns with "select all that apply" will have a blank top row, and the column heading will be the row below. This is only an issue for those types of questions.

With this in mind, I wrote a loop to go through all columns and replace the column names with the value from the second row if the column name was blank- which has a character length of 1.

Then, you can kill the second row of the data and have a tidy data frame.

```
for(i in 1:ncol(df)){
newname <- colnames(df)[i]
if(nchar(newname) < 2){
colnames(df)[i] <- df[1,i]
} 

df <- df[-1,]
```

Answer (score 1):

Coming to the party late, but this is still an issue and the best workaround I've found is using a function to paste the column names and sub-column names together, based on repeating values.

For instance, if exporting to `.csv`, the repeated column names will automatically be replaced with an `X` in RStudio. If exporting to `.xlsx`, the repeated value will be `...`.

Here's a `base R` solution:

```
sm_header_function <- function(x, rep_val){
  
  orig <- x
  
  sv <- x
  sv <- sv[1,]
  sv <- sv[, sapply(sv, Negate(anyNA)), drop = FALSE]
  sv <- t(sv)
  sv <- cbind(rownames(sv), data.frame(sv, row.names = NULL))
  names(sv)[1] <- "name"
  names(sv)[2] <- "value"
  sv$grp <- with(sv, ave(name, FUN = function(x) cumsum(!startsWith(name, rep_val))))
  sv$new_value <- with(sv, ave(name, grp, FUN = function(x) head(x, 1)))
  sv$new_value <- paste0(sv$new_value, " ", sv$value)
  new_names <- as.character(sv$new_value)
  colnames(orig)[which(colnames(orig) %in% sv$name)] <- sv$new_value
  orig <- orig[-c(1),]
  return(orig)
}

sm_header_function(df, "X")
sm_header_function(df, "...")
```

With some sample data, the change in column names would look like this:

**Original export from SurveyMonkey:**

```
> colnames(sample)
 [1] "Respondent ID"                                 "Please provide your contact information:"      "...11"                                        
 [4] "...12"                                         "...13"                                         "...14"                                        
 [7] "...15"                                         "...16"                                         "...17"                                        
[10] "...18"                                         "...19"                                         "I wish it would have snowed more this winter."
```

**Cleaned export from SurveyMonkey:**

```
> colnames(sample_clean)
 [1] "Respondent ID"                                            "Please provide your contact information: Name"           
 [3] "Please provide your contact information: Company"         "Please provide your contact information: Address"        
 [5] "Please provide your contact information: Address 2"       "Please provide your contact information: City/Town"      
 [7] "Please provide your contact information: State/Province"  "Please provide your contact information: ZIP/Postal Code"
 [9] "Please provide your contact information: Country"         "Please provide your contact information: Email Address"  
[11] "Please provide your contact information: Phone Number"    "I wish it would have snowed more this winter. Response"
```

Sample data:

```
structure(list(`Respondent ID` = c(NA, 11385284375, 11385273621, 
11385258069, 11385253194, 11385240121, 11385226951, 11385212508
), `Please provide your contact information:` = c("Name", "Benjamin Franklin", 
"Mae Jemison", "Carl Sagan", "W. E. B. Du Bois", "Florence Nightingale", 
"Galileo Galilei", "Albert Einstein"), ...11 = c("Company", "Poor Richard's", 
"NASA", "Smithsonian", "NAACP", "Public Health Co", "NASA", "ThinkTank"
), ...12 = c("Address", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ...13 = c("Address 2", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ...14 = c("City/Town", "Philadelphia", 
"Decatur", "Washington", "Great Barrington", "Florence", "Pisa", 
"Princeton"), ...15 = c("State/Province", "PA", "Alabama", "D.C.", 
"MA", "IT", "IT", "NJ"), ...16 = c("ZIP/Postal Code", "19104", 
"20104", "33321", "1230", "33225", "12345", "8540"), ...17 = c("Country", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), ...18 = c("Email Address", "benjamins@gmail.com", 
"mjemison@nasa.gov", "stargazer@gmail.com", "dubois@web.com", 
"firstnurse@aol.com", "galileo123@yahoo.com", "imthinking@gmail.com"
), ...19 = c("Phone Number", "215-555-4444", "221-134-4646", 
"999-999-4422", "999-000-1234", "123-456-7899", "111-888-9944", 
"215-999-8877"), `I wish it would have snowed more this winter.` = c("Response", 
"Strongly disagree", "Strongly agree", "Neither agree nor disagree", 
"Strongly disagree", "Disagree", "Agree", "Strongly agree")), row.names = c(NA, 
-8L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Two solutions that can work in 2023:

1. Use the `haven()` package
2. Use my cool R package!

### 1. Use the `haven` package

Haven is an R package that imports and exports Stata, SPSS and SAS files. If you select the 'SPSS' option when exporting from SurveyMonkey, you can use Haven to read the export, which will be a `.sav` file:

##### Export interface:

[image: SurveyMonkey interface to download .sav file]

##### Reading the file in R with `haven::read_sav()`

```r
library(haven)
read_sav("your-file-here.sav")
```

The resulting file will be a tibble (a type of dataframe). The columns are labeled with a 'q000N' syntax, and may contain filetypes unique to the haven package, such as numeric vectors with the class `haven_labelled`, which are analogous to factors.

#### 2. Use my cool package

I've created a [one-function package](https://github.com/church-army/monkeyreadr) that uses tidyverse functions to read and clean SM results from the weird format that they get exported in by default.

So if you want, you can do:

```r
devtools::install_github("church-army/monkeyreadr")
library(monkeyreadr)
read_sm("your-survey-monkey-data.csv")
```

For posterity, I will include the body of the function below:

##### `read_sm()` function

```r
default_cols <- c("Respondent ID", "Collector ID", "IP Address", 
                  "Email Address",  "First Name", "Last Name",
                  "Custom Data 1")

read_sm <- function(x, clean_names = TRUE, drop_surplus_cols = TRUE,
                    ...){

  ## determine cleaning function from clean_names -------------------
  stopifnot(length(clean_names) == 1)

  if(!is.function(clean_names)){
    name_cleaner <- ifelse(clean_names, janitor::make_clean_names, identity)
  } else name_cleaner <- clean_names

  ## read sm_data ---------------------------------------------------
  suppressMessages({
    sm_data <- vroom::vroom(x, show_col_types = FALSE, ...)
    })

  missing_names <- stringr::str_detect(names(sm_data), "^\\.\\.\\.\\d+$")

  sm_data <- dplyr::rename_with(sm_data, name_cleaner, everything())

  ## Assign correct types (where known) ----------------------------------------

  default_cols <- name_cleaner(default_cols)

  sm_data <-
    dplyr::mutate(
      sm_data,
      dplyr::across(
        dplyr::any_of(default_cols), as.character)
      )

  sm_data <-
    dplyr::mutate(
      sm_data,
      dplyr::across(any_of(name_cleaner(c("Start Date", "End Date"))),
                    lubridate::mdy_hms
      )
    )

  ## Replace missing names w/ values from first row ----------------------------
  first_row <- unlist(sm_data[1, ])
  sm_data <- sm_data[-1, ]

  repaired_names <- 
    name_cleaner(paste(first_row[missing_names], which(missing_names)))
  
old_names <- names(sm_data)[missing_names]

  names(sm_data)[missing_names] <- repaired_names

  if(length(repaired_names) > 0){

    repaired_names_to_print <-
      paste(old_names, "->", repaired_names, sep = " ")

    rlang::inform(message = "Repaired names:",
                  class = "sm_name_repair",
                  body = repaired_names_to_print
                  )
  }


  ## Drop surplus columns ------------------------
  if(drop_surplus_cols){

    all_na <- \(x) all(is.na(x))

    sm_data <- dplyr::select(sm_data, -(any_of(default_cols) & where(all_na)))

  }

  sm_data
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the following: use `read.csv()` with `header=FALSE`. Make two arrays, one with the two lines of headings and one with the answers to the survey. Then `paste()` the two rows/sentences of together. Finally, use `colnames()`.

Comment: As the second line starts with null characters this just won't work I'm afraid.

Comment: How about `if(!is.null(second.line)) { paste(first.line, second.line) }` ?

Comment: unfortunately there is useful information on the second.line even though it starts with a null character!